# Is it possible to set a period of time in the past when using present perfect?

Tags: grammar

I know that " I have worked there for 10 years " is a correct usage of present perfect but I was wondering if " I have worked there from 2000 to 2010 " is correct or not.

Comment: No. With a date range you need the simple past tense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a native speaker, but I hope this helps.
When using present perfect simple you are emphasizing the action in a sentence.

> E.g. *I have done my homework.*
> The present perfect simple is putting emphasis on the fact that you did your homework.

Present perfect continuous on the other hand, stresses the time range.

> E.g. *I have been doing my homework since 4 o'clock.*
> With the Present perfect continuous you are emphasizing the fact that you have been doing homework for a long period of time instead of the actual action itself.

Now, present perfect simple and present perfect continuous refer to an action that is completed and to an ongoing action that started sometime in the past, respectively.

Since the fact that you worked there from 2000 to 2010 is completed but WAS NOT MOMENTARY (it was continuous) at some point in the PAST, the correct usage is either past perfect simple or past perfect continuous.

> *I had worked there from 2000 to 2010* (past perf. simple)
> *I had been working there from 2000 to 2010* (past perf. continuous)
> Again, check if you want to stress the time range or the action, in order to determine whether to use the simple or continuous form of the tense.